# How to filter Email Messages by Subject Body & HasAttachments using C# Graph API

Tags: c#, linq, filter, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

```
var inboxMessages = await graphClient.Me
              .MailFolders["Inbox"]
              .Messages
              .Request()
              .Select("sender,subject")
              .Top(5)
              .GetAsync();
```

I want to filter the messages by `subject` and `hasAttachment` using C#

I am seeing few examples like this ,but how we need implement this in C# in above code?

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:search term"
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(subject, 'my search term')
```

Can anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter messages with attachments based on the subject that contains specific text like this

```
var subjectText = "your text";
var inboxMessages = await graphClient.Me
            .MailFolders["Inbox"]
            .Messages
            .Request()
            .Select("sender,subject")
            .Filter($"hasAttachments eq true and contains(subject,'{subjectText}')")
            .Top(5)
            .GetAsync();
```

Documentation:

[$filter query operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter#examples-using-the-filter-query-operator)

Comment: Thanks for the help.It worked. Is there a way to read only UnRead Messages ? Also please share the reference links.

Comment: @Sandeep It's better to create a new question how to read only unread messages but try var messages = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.Request().Filter("isread eq false").GetAsync();